# how to send pygame screen using socket programming

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, serversocket

I tried to send my pygame screen to my another pc using socket programming but it give error in client.py Actually in new in pygame so why these happen i didn't get it

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "webclient.py", line 24, in
>   
>       image = pygame.image.fromstring(dataset,(320,240),"RGB") # convert received image from string ValueError: String length does not equal
>   format and resolution size

and on server.py

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/gaurav/Desktop/Games_Project/panda.py", line 35, in 
>       image = screen.blit(bg, (0, 0)) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'blit'

Here is my **server.py**

```
import pygame
import socket
import os
import time
width=800
height=600
fps=60
port=5012
imgdir=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"img")
serversocket =socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(("",port))
serversocket.listen(1)
pygame.init()
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
screen=pygame.display.set_caption("Game by Players")
bg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(imgdir,"starfield.png")).convert()

running=True
while running:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    image = screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    data = pygame.image.tostring(image, "RGB")  # convert captured image  to string, use RGB color scheme
    connection.sendall(data)
    connection.close()
 pygame.quit()
```

Here is my **client.py**

```
import socket
import pygame
import sys

host = "127.0.0.1"
port=5012
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320,240),0)
while True:
    clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    clientsocket.connect((host, port))
    received = []
# loop .recv, it returns empty string when done, then transmitted data is completely received
    while True:
        recvd_data = clientsocket.recv(230400)
    if not recvd_data:
        break
    else:
        received.append(recvd_data)

dataset = ''.join(received)
image = pygame.image.fromstring(dataset,(320,240),"RGB") # convert received image from string
screen.blit(image,(0,0)) # "show image" on the screen
pygame.display.update()

# check for quit events
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "webclient.py", line 24,
in image = pygame.image.fromstring(dataset,(320,240),"RGB") # convert received image from string
ValueError: String length does not equal format and resolution size
```

I'm not sure you understand exactly what blit does. It will push an image to a spot on the screen. Its return value is a **pygame.Rect** object, but it looks like you were expecting an image.

Then, you are attempting to send this **pygame.Rect** object, and this error will occur, because your code is expecting a string that holds an image, but it is receiving a string representing a **pygame.Rect** object.

It appears you are trying to send the **bg** image. To do that, change this code inside of **server.py**:

```
data = pygame.image.tostring(image, "RGB")  # convert captured image  to string, use RGB color scheme
```

to

```
data = pygame.image.tostring(bg, "RGB")  # convert captured image  to string, use RGB color scheme
```

### Second Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "panda.py", line 35,
in image = screen.blit(bg, (0, 0)) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'blit'
```

Look at these lines:

```
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
screen=pygame.display.set_caption("Game by Players")
```

In the first line, you correctly create a **pygame.Surface** to display on. In the second line, you are attempting to set the window caption. This is where your error occurs. Look at the pygame docs for this function:

```
pygame.display.set_caption()
    Set the current window caption
    set_caption(title, icontitle=None) -> None
```

The function returns None! This means your **screen** is now equal to None when you attempt to call **screen.blit**, hence the error.

To fix the problem change this line:

```
screen=pygame.display.set_caption("Game by Players")
```

to

```
pygame.display.set_caption("Game by Players")
```

Comment: How to create multiplayer game using pygame and socket programming

Comment: I am not here to write your program. I have helped fix your errors, and now do the work necessary to achieve what you want.

Comment: I only wants the concept of multiplayer game

Comment: A multiplayer game is way beyond the scope of your abilities. Consider starting smaller, with a game that you can actually finish.